# Underline button animation

Tags: css

I can't understand ho I can replicate this effect on button, like in this theme:(scroll below and look where button say "read more") https://hiroshi.qodeinteractive.com

my button class: border-button

```
    .border-button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.border-button::before {
  content: "";
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
}

.border-button:hover::before {
  color: black;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
a:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant HTMLf or this CSS? I imagine it's probably just an `<a>` element with a class, but looking at CSS that doesn't work to try and guess the associated HTML to suggest answers to a problem is rarely successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS transition allows you to change property values smoothly, over a given duration.

Try using the transition property with background properties like this:

```css
.myanime {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 33%,#0000 33% 66%,#000 66%);
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 300% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.myanime:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition: background-position 1s;
}
```

```html
<span class="myanime">read more</span>
```

Comment: Maybe if you explain how the answer works, what it's doing, it might be more useful? (Yes, *I* can see what it's doing, but please [edit] your answer so that it's useful for the OP - and future visitors - as a learning resource.)

Comment: @Rizeen why if i set the animation of the line to white, it doesn't work?

Comment: Because the background is also white, it is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering how it works,

1. The background image is basically a line(linear gradient) that has transparent and black stripes. which we are positioning at the bottom right position.
2. we are then just increasing its width such that it encompasses the entire bottom
3. After that we apply a style (transition) on hover to it to change the position of the background position from bottom-right to the bottom-left.
4. Now, since the line is of greater length now it appears that the line is circling or going in a circular way.

I have decreased the length in the first `span` to show the difference

```css
.line1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 33%,#0000 33% 66%,#000 66%);
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 80% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.line2{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 33%,#0000 33% 66%,#000 66%);
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 300% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.line1:hover, .line2:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition: background-position 1s;
}
```

```html
<span class="line1">read more1</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<span class="line2">read more2</span>
```